Advice needed for Gradle build - Transitive dependencies (declared as API) not showing up in compile class path of Java Consumer
Posting here for feedback/advice.
I have a Java library - Lib and a Java Project - Consumer, somehow dependencies of Lib (declared as API  - which should be exposed to consumers) are not read/called in by java project Consumer.
Issue: When Java project Consumer try calling Java Library Lib, the dependencies declared as API are not called in the compile class path (of Consumer). This only happen after build and publish to remote repository (internal company server). However, when testing locally (build & publish to Maven local), API dependencies are called correctly.
Any tips/feedback/advice is appreciated!!! Thank you!
Below is the build.gradle file for Lib and Consumer :
Lib:

plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'distribution'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

dependencies {
    api ("lib-1-to-be-exposed-to-consumer")
    api ("lib-2--to-be-exposed-to-consumer")
    implementation ("lib-3-to-be-used-internally")
}

java {
    withSourcesJar()
}

publishing {
    publications {
    library(MavenPublication) {
        from components.java
        }
    }
}

tasks.withType(GenerateMavenPom).all {
    destination = "$buildDir/libs/${project.name}-${version}.pom"
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven url {interalCompanyRepository}
}

build.finalizedBy generatePomFileForLibraryPublication

Consumer:

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'distribution'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

dependencies {
    implementation ("Lib")
}
...

